# how to remove substring PHP with different format

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, substring

I have array of string like below :

1. RMB 1.342.100 Installment 6 x RMB 237.458
2. RMB 1.445.100 Installment 6 x RMB 242.458

etc

How to remove substring "Installment 6 x RMB 242.458" and "Installment 6 x RMB 242.458" ? so the output is only RMB 1.342.100 and RMB 1.445.100

Comment: this problem is REALLY easy. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: explode it by installment then get the first piece

Comment: i was using PREG_REPLACE, but I didnt understand about the pattern.

Comment: @Ghost : i want to use PREG_REPLACE, not using use explode

Comment: What's the problem with explode?

Comment: @cakan `explode()` generates another array that allocates memory, `preg_replace()` or `substr()` is faster and doesnt need to allocate more (useless) memory

Comment: yes thats why I would like to use preg_replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two solutions:

if your array is something like this:

```
$ar = array(
   "RMB 1.342.100 Installment 6 x RMB 237.458",
   "RMB 1.445.100 Installment 6 x RMB 242.458",
);
```

you can use `substr()` combined with `strpos()`

```
foreach($ar as&$a) {
    $a = substr($a,0,strpos($a," ",4)); // notice the offset in strpos so it doesn't match the first whitespace
}
```

or `preg_replace()`

```
foreach($ar as&$a) {
    $a = preg_replace("/\ Installment(.*)$/","",$a);
}
```

Comment: it should be preg_replace("/\Installment(.*)$/","",$a), but it works. Thank you super !!

Comment: i've added the whitespace before Installment, so that will get replaced too

Answer (score 0):

$str1= 'RMB 1.342.100 Installment 6 x RMB 237.458';

$str2 = 'RMB 1.445.100 Installment 6 x RMB 242.458';

$new_str1 = ltrim(str_replace('Installment 6 x RMB 237.458','',$str1)) ;

$new_str2 = ltrim(str_replace('Installment 6 x RMB 242.458','',$str2)) ;

echo $new_str1;
echo $new_str2;

output....

RMB 1.342.100

RMB 1.445.100